# How can i make Bootstrap collapse work properly with nested AngularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When i click any of the collapse toggle icons, it only works for the first `li` generated by the `ng-repeat`, how can i fix this so it only collapses it's parent `li`?

```js
$scope.data = [{
  label: 'North America',
  children: [{
    label: 'Canada',
    children: ['Toronto', 'Vancouver']
  }, {
    label: 'USA',
    children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
  }, {
    label: 'Mexico',
    children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
  }]
}, {
  label: 'South America',
  children: [{
    label: 'Venezuela',
    children: ['Caracas', 'Maracaibo']
  }, {
    label: 'Brazil',
    children: ['Sao Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro']
  }, {
    label: 'Argentina',
    children: ['Buenos Aires', 'Cordoba']
  }]
}];
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in data">
    <ul class="collapse in" ng-if="item.children" id="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse"></i>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right hidden"></i>
      {{item.label}}
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="sub in item.children">
        {{sub.label}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$index` to ensure you're targeting unique ids. So make the following 2 changes to your code:

- On the inner `<ul>` tag, `id="collapse{{ $index }}"`
- On the first `<i>` tag, `data-target="#collapse{{ $index }}"`

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in data">
    <ul class="collapse in" ng-if="item.children" id="collapse{{ $index }}">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{ $index }}"></i>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right hidden"></i>
      {{item.label}}
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="sub in item.children">
        {{sub.label}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**Sample Plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pnuaS7XgAKvpXkuDh57T?p=preview)

Comment: No problem, pleased it helped. :)

Comment: Saved me hours of debugging. :) Thanks @MatthewCawley