# ng-repeat not working with bootstrap collapse

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using a bootstrap 4 card to make a blog post and when you click on the View Comments link it should open a collapsed div in the card-footer where all the comments will show. The collapse was working correctly with hard coded html and even with dynamic data {{blog.title}} which is repeated before the collapse div. But if I try to add an ng-repeat='comment in blog.comments' to the card-body in the footer the view comments button won't even open the collapse. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149402/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-collapse-work-properly-with-nested-angularjs-ng-repeat) and tried to implement the $index but either I didn't do it correctly or the solution did not work for me some I'm going to post my original code before trying that fix.

blog Object from first ng-repeat

```
{
"_id": {"$oid": "5a6a426145cc5a2414ef06c4"},
"publishDate": {"$date": "2018-01-25T20:47:29.182Z"},
"comments": [
    {
        "_id": {"$oid": "5a6a429145cc5a2414ef06c5"},
        "username": "Rawle Juglal",
        "comment": "My first comment",
        "blog": {"$oid": "5a6a426145cc5a2414ef06c4"}
    },
    {
        "_id": {"$oid": "5a6a42a645cc5a2414ef06c6"},
        "username": "Phoenix Juglal",
        "comment": "A comment for deleting",
        "blog": {"$oid": "5a6a426145cc5a2414ef06c4"}
    }
],
"title": "My Coaching Philosophy",
"body": "This will be the first post in my new blog",
"__v": 2
```

}

blog.html

```
<div class='container-fluid screen-bg'>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-12 text-center'> ...</div><!--End of col-12-->
</div><!--End of row-->
<div class='row pb-3' ng-repeat='blog in $ctrl.blogs'>
    <div class='col-12'>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-3 col-md-2'>...</div><!--End of col-md-2-->
                    <div class='col-9 col-md-7'>
                        <h3 class='d-sm-none denim'>{{blog.title}}</h3>
                    </div><!--End of col-md-7-->
                    <div class='col-12 col-md-3'>
                        <p class='d-sm-none denim'>{{blog.publishDate | date:'mediumDate'}}</p>
                    </div><!--End of col-md-3-->
                </div><!--End of row-->
            </div><!--End of card-header-->
            <div class='card-body'>...</div><!--End of card body-->
            <div class='card-footer'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-12'>
                        <a class='float-right view-link' data-toggle='collapse' href="#commentDiv" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="commentDiv"><u><span class='h4'><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> View Comments</span></u></a>
                    </div><!--End of col-12-->
                    <div class='col-12'>
                        <div class="collapse" id="commentDiv">
                          <div class="card card-body" ng-repeat='comment in blog.comments'>
                            Some text
                            <p>{{comment.username}}</p>
                          </div><!--End of card-body-->
                        </div><!--End of commentDiv-->
                    </div><!--End of col-12-->
                </div><!--End of row-->         
            </div><!--End of card footer-->
        </div><!--End of card-->
    </div><!--End of col-12-->
</div><!--End of row-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try concatenating the id you had (`commentDiv`) with the `$index` (AngularJS index in the ng-repeat). This way you generate unique identifier for Bootstrap to work. Like this (posted only relevant part of the code):

```
<div class='row pb-3' ng-repeat='blog in $ctrl.blogs track by $index'>

...

<div class='col-12'>
     <a class='float-right view-link' data-toggle='collapse' href="#commentDiv{{$index}}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="commentDiv{{$index}}"><u><span class='h4'><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> View Comments</span></u></a>
</div><!--End of col-12-->

...

<div class="collapse" id="commentDiv{{$index}}">
     <div class="card card-body" ng-repeat='comment in blog.comments'>
           Some text
          <p>{{comment.username}}</p>
     </div><!--End of card-body-->
 </div><!--End of commentDiv-->
```

Comment: Ok, I triple checked to make sure I had no syntax errors when making your changes but it still wasn't opening with these changes.

Comment: @RawleJuglal Could you please post a JSFiddle or any similar in order to reproduce the issue? I've done this myself a couple of times and it has always worked as expected.

Comment: @RawleJuglal, Also, check if using `data-target` instead of `href` works in your case and let me know, please.

Comment: I haven't used JSFiddle but I can give it a shot to recreate it. It will have to be later this evening cause I have an appointment to make now. But I can also leave this link to the github if that is useful.https://github.com/RawleJuglal/2018RawleJuglal/tree/development. If it's not sorry, I haven't done this much.

Comment: I quickly tried to remove href and did replaced it with data-target="#commentDiv{{$index}}". If that syntax was right it did not work with this change.

Comment: Yes that is the correct syntax for `data-target`. If it doesn't work there must be other issue going there. When you find the time, make that [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and I'll check it out in order to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163909/discussion-between-rawle-juglal-and-lealceldeiro).

Comment: For anyone looking here in the future. This solution was correct although the collapse also worked without the index once I had the correct data to display.My blog object in the description was incorrect. I thought I had the comments objects in the array and it turns out I did not.